# (python) BeautifulSoup syntax, retrieve first paragraph

Tags: python, parsing, syntax, beautifulsoup

Trying the following code doesn't seem to work out for me quite as planned:
    from beautifulsoup import BeautifulSoup

```
definition = """From encyclopedia:\n<i></i><p>Infobox Country<br>fullcountryname=Thailand  &#x0E23;&#x0E32;&#x0E0A;&#x0E2D;&#x0E32;&#x0E13;&#x0E32;&#x0E08;&#x0E31;&#x0E01;&#x0E23;&#x0E44;&#x0E17;&#x0E22;Raja-anachakra Thai <br>image_flag= Flag of Thailand.svg <br>image_coa= Coat of arms of Thailand.png <br>image_location= LocationThailand.png <br>nationalmotto= none <br>nationalsong= Phleng Chat <br>nationalflower= n/a <br>nationalanimal= n/a <br>officiallanguages= Thai (<r><i>Thai language</i></r>) <br>populationtotal= 65,444,371 <br>populationrank= 19 <br>populationdensity= 127 <br>countrycapital= <r>Bangkok</r> <br>countrylargestcity= <r>Bangkok</r> <br>areatotal= 514,000 <br>arearank= 49 <br>areawater= n/a <br>areawaterpercent= 0.4 <br>establishedin= <r>April 7</r>, <r>1782</r> <br>leadertitlename=    <br>currency= <r>Baht</r> <br>utcoffset= +7 <br>dialingcode= 66 <br>internettld= .th<p><b>Thailand</b> is a <r>country</r> in Southeast <r>Asia</r>.  Its edges touch <r>Laos</r>, <r>Cambodia</r>, <r>Malaysia</r>, and <r>Myanmar</r> (which is also called Burma.) Thailand was called Siam until 1949."""

print BeautifulSoup(definition).find('p[1]').text
```

This does not return anything.. I'm sure it's a syntax error with my use of BeautifulSoup, has anybody got any idea how I could simply get:

```
Infobox Country
fullcountryname=Thailand Raja-anachakra Thai 
image_flag= Flag of Thailand. svg 
image_coa= Coat of arms of Thailand. png 
image_location= LocationThailand. png 
nationalmotto= none 
nationalsong= Phleng Chat 
nationalflower= n/a 
nationalanimal= n/a 
officiallanguages= Thai (Thai language) 
populationtotal= 65,444,371 
populationrank= 19 
populationdensity= 127 
countrycapital= Bangkok 
countrylargestcity= Bangkok 
areatotal= 514,000 
arearank= 49 
areawater= n/a 
areawaterpercent= 0. 4 
establishedin= April 7, 1782 
leadertitlename=  
currency= Baht 
utcoffset= +7 
dialingcode= 66 
internettld= . th
```

Thank you :)

EDIT: I would actually prefer if I could get the text between the word "Infobox" and the last

tag, so that I could use the script to parse live wikipedia pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using XPath syntax, which Beautiful Soup doesn't support. Lattyware's answer is correct. As for the question in your edit, you can use Beautiful Soup 4's [.stripped_strings generator](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) to get approximately what you want. Some example code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(definition)

import re
infobox_start = re.compile("^Infobox") 

start_at = soup.find(text=infobox_start)
for string in start_at.parent.stripped_strings:
    print string
```

Answer (score 4):

[`find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20%2a%2akwargs%29) only matches the first element, so just use `find('p')`.

```
>>>print BeautifulSoup(definition).find('p').text
Infobox Countryfullcountryname=Thailand  &#x0E23;&#x0E32;&#x0E0A;&#x0E2D;&#x0E32;&#x0E13;&#x0E32;&#x0E08;&#x0E31;&#x0E01;&#x0E23;&#x0E44;&#x0E17;&#x0E22;Raja-anachakra Thaiimage_flag= Flag of Thailand.svgimage_coa= Coat of arms of Thailand.pngimage_location= LocationThailand.pngnationalmotto= nonenationalsong= Phleng Chatnationalflower= n/anationalanimal= n/aofficiallanguages= Thai (Thai language)populationtotal= 65,444,371populationrank= 19populationdensity= 127countrycapital=Bangkokcountrylargestcity=Bangkokareatotal= 514,000arearank= 49areawater= n/aareawaterpercent= 0.4establishedin=April 7,1782leadertitlename=currency=Bahtutcoffset= +7dialingcode= 66internettld= .th
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is the Infobox you are looking for, you might find that [DBpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBpedia) gives you powerful programmatic, and more stable access to the data. Of course, the Wikipedia API and the [python wikitools](http://code.google.com/p/python-wikitools/) also offers this.

There is a learning curve to both these solutions, but may be more stable and respectful of the site than scraping.